# How do you compress a user-uploaded a user-uploaded folder with client-side JS?

Tags: javascript, html, compression

I am creating a basic page that uses the new CompressionStream API gzip compression features to take a user's folder and compress it to a .gz with client-side JS.

Here's an example of compression with gzip:

```
const compressedReadableStream = inputReadableStream.pipeThrough(
  new CompressionStream("gzip"),
);
```

In this example a function decompresses a blob using gzip:

```
async function DecompressBlob(blob) {
  const ds = new DecompressionStream("gzip");
  const decompressedStream = blob.stream().pipeThrough(ds);
  return await new Response(decompressedStream).blob();
}
```

I have gotten the compression and decompression working for file uploads, and even got it working for uploads of multiple files at once, but cannot get it to work for directories, which makes it pretty much useless.

I have tried creating the most basic setup possible, but have found that compressing a directory to a file just makes it a file, no longer a folder of files. This is my current setup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>File Upload and Compression</title>
</head>
<body>

<input type="file" id="fileInput" multiple webkitdirectory>

<button onclick="groupAndCompress()">Group and Compress</button>

<script>
async function groupAndCompress() {
  const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
  const files = fileInput.files;

  if (files.length === 0) {
    alert('Please select at least one file or folder.');
    return;
  }

  const groupedFiles = groupFiles(files);
  const compressedBlob = await compressFiles(groupedFiles);

  // You can use the compressedBlob as needed (e.g., download or display)
  console.log('Compressed Blob:', compressedBlob);
}

function groupFiles(files) {
  const groupedFiles = {};

  for (const file of files) {
    const path = file.webkitRelativePath || file.name;

    if (!(path in groupedFiles)) {
      groupedFiles[path] = [];
    }

    groupedFiles[path].push(file);
  }

  return groupedFiles;
}

async function compressFiles(groupedFiles) {
  const compressedParts = [];

  for (const path in groupedFiles) {
    const files = groupedFiles[path];
    const blobs = await Promise.all(files.map(fileToBlob));
    const concatenatedBlob = new Blob(blobs, { type: 'application/zip' });

    const compressedStream = concatenatedBlob.stream().pipeThrough(new CompressionStream('gzip'));
    const compressedBlob = await new Response(compressedStream).blob();

    compressedParts.push(compressedBlob);
  }

  const finalBlob = new Blob(compressedParts, { type: 'application/zip' });
  return finalBlob;
}

function fileToBlob(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function () {
      resolve(new Blob([reader.result], { type: file.type }));
    };

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am aware of JSzip, but built-in web features can perform this faster and don't require fetching a script.

Comment: How would you upload a folder? I didn't even know this is possible.

Comment: @jabaa <input type="file" multiple webkitdirectory> can be used to upload directories